# How to print tree elements ending in "ire" in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, tree

I am trying to print tree elements in Pre Order (Root, Left and Right) in Clojure for a given tree structure.

Below is the code prints the elements in Pre order, but I am not able to figure out how to apply the condition  to check that the string ends with "ire".

I tried using Filter and When as well. Can someone help here please?

```
(defn preorder [tree]
  (if (nil? (:root tree))
    (str nil)
    (let [v (:root  tree)
          l (:left  tree)
          r (:right tree)]
      (str v
           (str " ")
           (str l (str " ") (preorder l))
           (str " ")
           (str r (str " ")(preorder r))))))
```

Comment: I could not get what you are looking for. but `(.endsWith "fire" "ire")` can check whether `fire` ends with `ire`

Comment: This code is already traversing a tree, all i am looking for is how the condition has be to applied in code.This one :  (.endsWith "fire" "ire"). I tried doing (.endsWith tree "ire") , but this throws a Null pointer exception when i pass the left and right tree to this.

Comment: could you give us an example of the tree?

Comment: if `tree` returns anything useful for `(:root tree)` etc, than it isn't going to be valid to call the `endsWith` method on it. Are you talking about String as in the type on the jvm, or some tree representation where you are calling some path down a tree a string?

Comment: for anyone else curious, the readable version of that last line is `(str v " " l " " (preorder l) " " r " "(preorder r))`

Comment: And `(str nil)` is simply `""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- *Algorithm:* Generate a *sequence* of `:root` values walking the tree.
  Use the sequence library, `map` or `filter`, to convert it into strings
  or filter the nodes as need be.
- *Data:* Use `nil` values for `:left` and `:right` instead of for
  `:root`.

Thus:

```
(defn preorder [tree]
  (if tree
    (let [v (:root  tree)
          l (:left  tree)
          r (:right tree)]
      (cons v (concat (preorder l) (preorder r))))))
```

For example

```
(preorder {:root 5, :left {:root 10}})
;(5 10)

(filter even? (preorder {:root 5, :left {:root 10}}))
;(10)
```

Beware that you will run out of stack if your tree is too deep.

Comment: regarding the stack thing, I think replacing `concat` with `lazy-cat` would fix that issue

Comment: @noisesmith I wasn't sure. [`tree-walk`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4535) wraps the whole expression in a `lazy-seq`.

Comment: @noisesmith It probably would, but I would rather wrap the whole function body in a `lazy-seq` instead.